# Internet Explorer - Weird Copy Paste Bug

Tags: internet-explorer, copy-paste

At my work we use Internet Explorer for managing a shared email inbox.
Sometimes when I work work in the browser, and then go to another program (mozilla, chrome, word processor, etc) I Ctrl+V or paste option I get a random string of text rather than what I copied previously.

Text:

`<mc type="items" fid="LgAAAAAdrpcx4N2aR4/x+pcFDczoAQCHX70NMYAbQIYfhy8wM+9EAAAAAz8oAAAB"><itm><id>RgAAAAAdrpcx4N2aR4/x+pcFDczoBwCHX70NMYAbQIYfhy8wM+9EAAAAAz8oAACHX70NMYAbQIYfhy8wM+9EARix09ufAAAJ</id><t>IPM.Note</t><urlid>RgAAAAAdrpcx4N2aR4%2fx%2bpcFDczoBwCHX70NMYAbQIYfhy8wM%2b9EAAAAAz8oAACHX70NMYAbQIYfhy8wM%2b9EARix09ufAAAJ</urlid></itm></mc>`

This doesn't happen immediately after dealing with the internet explorer window. It will sometimes take a few interactions, such as opening an email or refreshing the page.

I have shown this error to my IT team and they are not quite sure what causes this. I decided to take this matter into my own hands and I am tired of losing important copy "data" and going back to the source that I copy something from.

Running: Windows 10, IE (not sure on as it doesn't show me the version info other than what is in this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ustAS.png).

Answer (score 0):

What did you copy in the email? It seems to be a form, and you may have copied the email format.

Have you tried other browsers, is there any problem you mentioned?

If you can describe more clearly how to reproduce your current problem, it will help to find related solutions, hope you can understand.

Comment: It was not a form. I can copy anything, and it doesn't have to be something I copied in internet explorer. I can copy an order number, just plain text, from Mozilla or Chrome, and then if I go and do anything in IE for a for moments and then go and paste it will show this weird text. This includes pasting to IE, Chrome, Mozilla, Word, basic text editor, etc.

Comment: Also, it does not happen when I access this email from another browser. However we only use IE to access this shared inbox as using other browsers will not show all of our folders we use to organize emails.

Comment: Copy and paste behavior differs according to whether you are viewing, reviewing, or editing a Word document in the browser, and whether you are pasting content from outside Word for the web. Maybe you could refer to this document: [Copy and paste in Office for the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-and-paste-in-office-for-the-web-682704da-8360-464c-9a26-ff44abf4c4fe)